# Scheduling a Cognos report based on Dates from a data warehouse table

Tags: cognos-11

We have a report already written for Student Services, but we need to schedule it for specific times in the term; these times are from the date table in our data warehouse.  For example, we need it on the first day of the term (one of the MANY dates defined in our date table), and two weeks prior to the first day of the term.  If the current date is either one of these dates, we need the report to run; otherwise no.  Should I use trigger-based Cognos reporting?  Is there a way to do it in regular Cognos scheduling?  Should I schedule it out of an external (Oracle) stored procedure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have a date table in our Data Warehouse which has the first day of the term, the fourth Monday of the term, etc.  I have to schedule reports in Cognos based on those dates from that table.  The report I have spoken of above has to be run two weeks before the start of the term (in Oracle, sysdate-14 has to equal the column called start_of_term - 14).  So should I use trigger-based Cognos reporting?  Is there a way to do this in regular Cognos scheduling?  Should I schedule it out of an external Oracle stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to set up Event Studio to first have a daily check to see if it is 14 days before term (had to add that to the date table), and 2 weeks after start of term (also in our date table).  Set up the run condition, set up tasks for the reports required, then set up the email.  Could not set up Run Agent in Event studio (IBM was singularly unhelpful here) so we scheduled it in Cognos.  It runs like a charm.